# I got a Creeper in my trap...and that's a bad thing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I made a simple water trap in Minecraft, but for some reason made it right next to my furnace and crafting table. I trapped a creeper in it, but now I realize I can't kill it without getting hurt because:

1. I have no snowballs or arrows to fire.
2. I can't set it on fire with flint and steel.
3. It is below me so it is hard to hit it with my sword.
   How do I kill it? Here is a picture:

[image: this was a bad idea]

Comment: Drop sand on it?

Comment: Move the furnace and crafting table?

Comment: @Batophobia too close to it methinks

Comment: "How do I kill it?" -> By jumping next to it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with situations like this is usually to not kill the creeper at all. Just [despawn it](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Despawning).

From that wiki link:

> - A mob will immediately despawn if ever there is no player within 128 blocks of it. Note that this appears to be a sphere, not a cylinder
>   from map top to bottom.
> - A mob that has had no player within 32 blocks of it for more than 30 seconds has a 1 in 800 chance of despawning on each game tick (1/20th
>   of a second). Therefore, the half-life of monsters not within 32
>   blocks of a player is 27.73 seconds, after the initial 30 seconds have
>   elapsed.

So, either wander a short distance away and wait, or wander a longer distance away, and the creeper will simply cease to exist, making the area safe again, at least until something else spawns in.

Comment: Also light the area so no new mobs will be spawned and trapped again?

Answer (score 12):

Based on the screenshot, you've got sufficent armor to survive a creeper blast. Hit the bugger with your sword until he either blows up or dies. Since he's in water, he won't be able to do any environmental damage.

Alternatively, grab a bow/arrow if you can scavenge one. Suffocation with sand or gravel also functions. These methods will allow you to collect exp and that gunpowder as well.

Comment: Since it's standing in water, its explosion will not break blocks, only hurt the player. The furnace and table are safe!

Answer (score 2):

Use sand to kill it!

Even if it blew up...it wouldn't be the end of the world. It's only a crafting table and furnace, just be glad it's not a chest.

Answer (score 0):

You can just hit it and then back off immediately and then repeat! 
 
I guess it'd be the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in SMP or you have cheats enabled, you can use `/gamerule mobGriefing false`.

Then, attack the creeper with reckless abandon!